# Qt Sql not able to bind variables to QSqlQuery prepare Statement

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, qt, qt-creator

I am trying to fetch some records from MySQL database by using a prepared statement by using QSqlQuery as:

```
 QString username=ui->textEdit_password->toPlainText();
 QString password=ui->textEdit_password->toPlainText();
 QSqlQuery query;
 query.prepare("SELECT * FROM login_access WHERE username=? AND password=?");
 query.addBindValue(username);
 query.addBindValue(password);
 query.exec();`
```

When i run :
 `std::string q_str1=query.executedQuery().toUtf8().constData();
  std::cout<<"Query : "<<q_str1<<"\n";`

It outputs : `Query : SELECT * FROM login_access WHERE username=? AND password=?` where the "?" has not been replaced and the query returns nothing since the "?" character is compared to the database records.

On running the query: `SELECT * FROM login_access`, the query returns all the database records in the login_access table.

I have also tried replacing the "?" with placeholders ":uname",":pass" and changed `query.addBindValue(username);` to `query.bindValue(":uname",username);`, and done same with password field.

I am running QtCreator 4.4.1
Thanks.

Comment: If you use named placeholders, your binding should use the same names. So you have to write `query.bindValue(":uname", username);`. Compare: ":user" vs ":uname".

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be `query.bindValue(":uname",username);`

Comment: You fill `username` and `password` from the same source, `ui->textEdit_password`. Could that be the issue? However, please make sure to provide a **tested** [mcve].

Comment: Additionally, [**storing cleartext passwords in databases is professional blunder**](https://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/). Get rid of that, use a cryptographic hash *now*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use query.bindValue( ...) because this sets the placeholder value.

I tested executedQuery() on one of my SQL statements with placeholders and it returned a string with just the placeholders, not the values. The documentation does say that in most cases it the same string as lastQuery().
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#executedQuery

You have confirmed that your SQL statement without the where clause works so the next stage is to check you are binding what you think you are binding. To do this use boundValue(const QString placeholder) to find out if the placehold value is being bound.

It might also be useful to check the query has run OK.

So, after your query.exec you should put the following (assuming these are your placeholders) just to check these things:

```
qDebug() << query.lasterError();
qDebug() << query.boundValue(":uname");
qDebug() << query.boundValue(":pass");
```

Comment: Thanks, It solved my problem. After using `query.boundValue()` , I was finally able to see the variables I was entering in the prepared statement, instead of seeing "?". I realised I was taking both the username and password variable from the password field.And all my queries were returning nothing because both fields were password variables.

Comment: According to [QSqlQuery doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#details) *Binding values using positional placeholders (version 2)* - OP code should work too though.

Comment: Yes, the OP code should have worked but he confirmed he was passing incorrect data into the SQL statement. For debugging, the documentation states that in most cases executedQuery() returns the same string as lastQuery() so in some cases it will return the placeholders not the placeholder values. I think it may be database dependent. My test on a SQLITE database returned the placeholders. Using boundValue() will return the data you are binding to the value so it will at least clarify what you are binding. It's useful if executedQuery() doesn't work.